# Xamarin Forms RelativeLayout nested inside StackLayout Cannot Set Height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm not sure if this is my misunderstanding, a bug or a known behaviour but it's stumped me so far.

Given this layout in a content page:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                 BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.948}"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1.0}">

        <RelativeLayout HeightRequest="1"
                        BackgroundColor="Blue">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
                  RowHeight="130"
                  SeparatorColor="White"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemCollection}">
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why can the height of the inner `RelativeLayout` never be less than the size shown below?

The image below shows this code running in an emulator with a `HeightRequest` of 1 on the inner `RelativeLayout`.

[image: Xamarin Forms image showing unexpected heights]

Comment: Just try by placing `<Grid>` with Two rows having height `1` and `*`  inside the your parent `<StackLayout>`, Place `RelativeLayout` in 1st row and `Listview` in 2nd row.

Comment: I ended up doing similar in my app. But I'd still like to know why this is behaving like this.